# GitLab pipelines pushes to remote server but cannot ssh

Tags: ssh, gitlab-ci

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
build app:
  stage: build
  only:
    - feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
  before_script:
    - echo "before script"
    - 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$GIT_URL" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - echo "HOST *" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
    - git config user.email "user.villiers@main.com"
    - git config user.name "user-main"
    - git remote add acquia $GIT_URL
  script:
    - echo "running the script"
    - git checkout -b feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
    - git push acquia feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
  after_script:
    - echo "time to ssh"
    - ssh maindecoupled.dev@maindecoupleddev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com "cd /var/www/html && ls -la && composer install && exit"
```

My pipeline gives a success, but when I look at the job result, I see a permission denied certainly from the after script.

The full result of the job is as follows:

```
$ echo "before script"
before script
$ command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
Agent pid 12
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
Identity added: (stdin) (userdevilliers@Norton-MacBook-Pro.local)
$ mkdir -p ~/.ssh
$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh
$ echo "$GIT_URL" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ echo "HOST *" > ~/.ssh/config
$ echo "StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config
$ git config user.email "user.villiers@main.com"
$ git config user.name "user-main"
$ git remote add acquia $GIT_URL
$ echo "running the script"
running the script
$ git checkout -b feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
Switched to a new branch 'feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2'
$ git push acquia feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
Warning: Permanently added 'svn-23449.prod.hosting.acquia.com,22.222.22.222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
To svn-23449.prod.hosting.acquia.com:maindecoupled.git
   b1f2c6ca..622cab3b  feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2 -> feature/ci-pipeline-job-v2
Running after_script
00:02
Running after script...
$ echo "time to ssh"
time to ssh
$ ssh maindecoupled.dev@maindecoupleddev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com "cd /var/www/html && ls -la && composer install && exit"
Warning: Permanently added 'maindecoupleddev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com,11.11.111.111' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
maindecoupled.dev@maindecoupleddev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com: Permission denied (publickey).
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

How am I able to push to the Acquia repo but have a public key error when its time to ssh?
Not sure how to go about from here.
How can I ssh into the remote server and cd into the intended directories?

Comment: Have you tried the ssh key manually?  It could be that SSH server it's not setup to handle publickey login (see: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server for reference)

Comment: Or perhaps you need to ensure the path to the public key is correct when you do the `ssh` command - i.e. `ssh -i /path/to/publickey maindecoupled.dev@maindecoupleddev.ssh.prod.acquia-sites.com`

Comment: @blurfus this is a bit off because I can push to the server...but going to your second comment, how do I get the path of the GitLab private key?

Comment: From your first comment, I don't understand what you mean by trying ssh key manually.

Comment: I mean you should try to login to the server manually (from command line or console/terminal) to ensure the credentials and key are working correctly

Comment: Locally I can ssh without problems. 
Since the job complains about the public key, am wondering if adding the private key in the before script is the issue. Though I would know how to reference the private key from GitLab

Comment: Yes, but the script is not running locally so the key needs to be somewhere accessible to the script (and then it can be used by it for the connection)